# ADF - Web Activity - 'String' does not match the field: 'body'

Tags: azure-data-factory

I created a Web Activity in ADF and I am trying to send data with the POST method.
According to the documentation, the body takes a String (or expression with resultType string). I want to use the @concat String Function as shown in the image below.

I get a warning that says:
Expression of type: 'String' does not match the field: 'body'

I am confused, String does not match the body? The documentation says, the body takes a String?
Can anyone help?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity

[image: 'String' does not match the field: 'body']

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should be an object type. Please use `@json('{"key": "value"}')`

Comment: How do add a system Variable TriggerName in the place of "value" in your JSON Example? `@pipeline().Pipeline` is the system variable. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#expressions)  is some documentation from Microsoft. It's not helpful.

Comment: @json() accepts string as parameter. Could you try `@json(concat('{"key": "', pipeline().TriggerName, '"}'))` please?

Comment: This was changed recently. Why hasn't the documentation been updated? "Body. Represents the payload that is sent to the endpoint. String (or expression with resultType of string)." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity